# How to get ordered coords using cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack (from bottom to top and left to right)

Tags: python, image, opencv, coordinates

## Hey Everybody!

I'm trying to extract the coordinates of the lines as depicted in the picture, but the retrieved coordinates are not ordered (either from left-right or bottom-top). Is there a way to do it?
[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAy0Y.png)
[Output image using goodFeaturesToTrack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glKkr.png)
I would like to acknowledge @Jeru Luke , @Baraa and @stateMachine for their privous answers in this regard.

I tried the following:

```
x_corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(h_BeamsCopy, None, 0.01, 10) # None: find all the corners
x_corners = np.int0(x_corners)
for i, hcorner enumerate(x_corners):
    xh, yh = hcorner.ravel()
    cv2.circle(h_BeamsCopy, (xh, yh), 5, (255,100,0), -1)
    cv2.putText(h_BeamsCopy, str(i), (int(xh), int(yh)), font, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 1)
```

I expected the retrieved points would be ordered from bottom-top and left-right as illustrated in the following picture:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ4B2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering of `goodFeaturesToTrack` is explained [in the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541):

> The remaining corners are sorted by the quality measure in the descending order.

You can sort them yourself based on position:

```py
x_corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(h_BeamsCopy, None, 0.01, 10) # None: find all the corners
x_corners = np.int0(x_corners)

# Flatten to x,y
corners = (corner.ravel() for corner in x_corners)
# Sort according to your pic (down-up, left-right -> y=0 is top, x=0 is left)
# y-axis is turned negative to use ascending sort in our favor
corners = sorted(corners, key=lambda c: (-1 * c[1], c[0]))
```

Sample output:

```py
>>> corners = [(2,5), (7,4), (849,590), (2, 590)]
>>> sorted(corners, key=lambda c: (-1 * c[1], c[0]))
[(2, 590), (849, 590), (2, 5), (7, 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I thought that there was an option for that since the goodFeaturesToTrack retrieves the coordinates of the points. Your answer is highly appreciated.